# add subitem to listview item after clicking an item

Tags: android, listview, subitem

I am working on an android application that I like to do something like this picture below to a listview:

[image]

as you can see, there's a custom adapter for a list view that generates a list out of one of my classes.
I want to add a view like a Linearlayout or something under a Listview item after I clicked it.
how can I do that?
PS: where I have to put an onItemClickListener()? in my adapter's class or in my main page after onCreate() method?
PPS: in the picture, I meant SUBITEM FOR ITEM1... sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to do what [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106921/nullpointerexeption-when-using-listview-inside-a-viewstub) does with a `ViewStub`, and implement an `OnClickListener` that is attached to each `ListItem`.

Please let me know if that is not clear or if you can't find a good example, and I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: okay I managed to use ViewStub, and managed to inflate it on an listview's itemclick. but when I click an item for the second time, the app crashes, I know why it crashesh because there is no viewstub remained in there it was inflated. how can I check if a viewstub is inflated so I won't get to an exception? and how can I deflate it? thanks...

Comment: and I coded the onclicklistener into the getView method in my adapter... is that right?